# Relationship between 2 folders - Alfresco

Tags: relationship, alfresco, directory, file-association, directory-structure

I'm reading the book AlfrescoCMIS, and the book refers a creation of a relationship between two folders in Alfresco. I run the code and I don't understand what is in fact this relationship, can anyone help me to understand what is a relationship between two folders or between two files?

Comment: What kind of relationship are you creating? And what are you creating it for?

Comment: Only for testing one example for the book, but i don't know what is relationships/associations with 2 folders or 2 files in Alfresco.

Comment: It's whatever you want it to be! You pick the type of the association you want, then add it! [This forum post has a quick intro](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/general/non-technical-alfresco-discussion/difference-between-associations-and-child)

Comment: I dont understand how to apply this different types and What this types make for the two folders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relationship or association is a link between two objects. A concrete example is "related documents". Suppose you create a PDF in your CMIS repository and that PDF is related to N other PDFs. You'd like to be able to ask that PDF for all of its related documents. So, one way to implement that is to create a "related documents" relationship between the source PDF and all of its related PDFs.

Relationships are typed, so you can define any kind of relationship that makes sense for your requirements.

My example describes a relationship between documents, but relationships can be created between folders and between folders and documents as well.

For a more detailed discussion on relationships, please refer to relationships section in the [CMIS specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-560006).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I understand :)